# jQuery looping over php array displaying content multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have this php array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name1
            [schedule] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attractie] => Hey
                            [start] => 0930
                            [end] => 1200
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [attractie] => There
                            [start] => 1300
                            [end] => 1400
                        )

                )

            [link] => link
            [color] => 964d11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name2
            [schedule] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attractie] => Hey
                            [start] => 1200
                            [end] => 1530
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [attractie] => There
                            [start] => 1000
                            [end] => 1100
                        )

                )

            [link] => link
            [color] => e49fca
        )

)
```

My goal is to get the `color` value so I wrote this loop:

```
var orders = <?php echo json_encode($myOrders); ?>;
jQuery.each( orders, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.color);
});
```

Now I am expecting the result to be this:

```
964d11
e49fca
```

But the result is actualy this:

```
964d11
e49fca
964d11
e49fca
964d11
e49fca
964d11
e49fca
```

Anyone has any idea what is going on here?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: You should first convert your `PHP Array` into `JavaScript Array` and traverse for better results.

Comment: I have tried your code and its also giving desire output. Working fine for me in PHP 5.5.12. Just I have copy and paste it in my local and work for me.

Comment: @RuchishParikh Hmm so weird :/

Comment: Do a `console.log()` for your `orders`. It probably doesn't show the same thing you mentioned in your PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

That should work as expected, have you tried to use `console.log(this.color);` ?

Otherwise, you can try this alternative:

```
for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){
    console.log(orders[i].color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var orders_json = '<?php echo json_encode($myOrders); ?>';
var orders = jQuery.parseJSON(orders_json);
jQuery.each(orders, function (key, value) {
     console.log(value['color']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

`var eachOrders = <?php echo json_encode($myOrders); ?>;
jQuery.each( eachOrder, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value[key][color]);
});`

Hope this will work